# Подгружаемые модули на C++

Tags: c++, модули, runtime

Есть ли стандартный или общепринятый способ разработки приложения с подгружаемыми модулями на C++? Имеются в виду бинарные модули, которые могут свободно подгружаться и выгружаться во время выполнения добавляя программе новый функционал.
Если возможно, дайте ссылки на материал по теме. Благодарю.

Comment: у меня так и не удалось заставить visual корректно отображать модули вообще, особенно "радует", что 3 компилятора не договорились о расширении файлов

Comment: это называется динамические библиотеки - .dll .so, не стоит их путать с модулями (modules - понятием С++).

Comment: Если что, вот ссылка по теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696653/dynamically-load-a-function-from-a-dll

Comment: Вот еще одна "Dynamically loading a class from a dll" https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20165

Comment: Аналоги на Линуксе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651803/loading-a-library-dynamically-in-linux-or-osx